# Why personal vpn configuration not working?

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, nevpnmanager

I'm developing a VPN application, which installs **personal** VPN profile into system configuration. If my application is only one VPN application on device - all works as expected. If I install one more VPN app with another **personal** VPN certificate, I have problems.

[image]
As you can see on screenshot, there are two **personal** certificates installed in system. One of them (not my app's certificate) is in selected state. When I try to connect to VPN from my app, my certificate does not go to selected state and VPN is not working. It works only when I select my app's certificate manually in settings.
But, when I try to connect to VPN from another app, this app automatically selects proper certificate in system settings and all is working correctly.

So, my question is: is there any API to select proper certificate before connecting to VPN?

I tried to use **NEVpnManager.isEnabled** with no luck. I also use **NEVPNManager.saveToPreferences()** before trying to connect to VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. The reason is `NEVPNManager.isEnabled` flag. It must be set to TRUE before method `saveToPreferences()` is called.